# Spring Native with RestTemplate - Type Definition Error even when using @RegisterReflectionForBinding

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, graalvm, spring-native

I'm new to Spring Native and GraalVM.
I Have a Spring Boot application which fetches data from another service using RestTemplate.
Using **@RegisterReflectionForBinding** I can successfuly fetch all queries, except for the following query and I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I get the following error (logged):

> 17:01:48 [taskScheduler-6] [9b5785a1-4637-40d6-9d4d-bed86ce913e0] ERROR AquaControllerCommunicatorService - fetchPlacerRecommendations error: **Type definition error: [collection type; class java.util.HashSet, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]**

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the method that does the fetching:

```
  @RegisterReflectionForBinding({PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto.class, HashSet.class, Set.class, PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto.PlacerRecommendationControllerRestDto.class})
public Optional<PlacerRecommendations> fetchPlacerRecommendations() {
    try {
        log.debug("Fetching placer recommendations");
        PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto placerRecommendationsControllerRestDto = restTemplate.getForObject("/api/v1/alg/placer", PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto.class);
        if (placerRecommendationsControllerRestDto == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        return Optional.of(placerRecommendationsControllerRestDto.toPlacerRecommendations());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("fetchPlacerRecommendations error: {}", e.getMessage());
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

and this is the fetched dto:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto {
    private LocalDateTime recommendationTime;
    private List<PlacerRecommendationsControllerRestDto.PlacerRecommendationControllerRestDto> placerRecommendations;

public PlacerRecommendations toPlacerRecommendations() {
    return new PlacerRecommendations(
            recommendationTime,
            placerRecommendations.stream().map(PlacerRecommendationControllerRestDto::toPlacerRecommendation).toList()
    );
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class PlacerRecommendationControllerRestDto {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private double altitude;
    private Set<String> consumersCovered;

    public PlacerRecommendation toPlacerRecommendation() {
        return new PlacerRecommendation(
                latitude,
                longitude,
                altitude,
                new HashSet<>(consumersCovered)
        );
    }
}
```

}

Of course, it works just fine when I run it with the JVM.

Comment: Changing the type of "consumersCovered" in the DTO from "Set" to "List" solved it.
Though I still can't figure out why this code works when it's running on the JVM and not with Spring-Native